# Delphi SOAP Web Server not triggering on SOAPActions

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl

I’m writing a client/server SOAP application in Delphi2005 that has to conform to a WSDL that was given to me. I know from previous experience that SOAP support is incredibly problematic in most versions of Delphi. I’m using some of the SOAP components from D2007 and XE to make some things better. I’ve done the accepted solution on the client side of the app. I’ve consumed the WSDL in SOAPUI and then I’m doing manual hacking of the XML stream outbound to generate valid XML. My issue is on the server side. It’s a CGI exe that I’ve created with the Delphi wizard. I put the proxy generated pas file and the invokable interface in the service exe. I’m able to get the Service Interface Page and I can look at the WSDL that the exe makes. However, SOAPUI isn’t able to properly consume the WSDL, it says it’s not able to find some of the object types. Also when I use SOAPUI to call my service, I’m only ever able to get into the DefaultHandlerAction on the WebModule. This all leads me to believe that the inbound XML I’m sending to my service isn’t matching enough to trigger the serializer on the server end. Is there anyway to hack the XML before it gets to the serializer in such a way that I can get it to properly trigger the SoapActions?